# I would like to know is it possible to achieve the pandas.groupby operation using list comprehension or apply method of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Pandas dataframe methods include a groupby,

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('battle.csv')
df[['region','location']].groupby('region').count()
```

This methods generates a dataframe that looks like

```
region    count     
 A           5
 B           2
 C           6
```

I am trying to implement the same operation using `df.apply()` or a list comprehension to familiarize myself with coding in python. Please suggest your opinions.

Comment: Do you think `df[['region','location']].groupby('region').apply(lambda x: x.count())`? Or need implemented `groupby`? Or some custom function like `(df[['region','location']].groupby('region').apply(custom_function))`?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please show your raw data and your attempts

Comment: I think the best is use highly optimezed pandas functions like `groupby`, `count` and only if need something special (or faster) use custom functions. Can you explain more?

Comment: @EdChum, agree with what you said, after doing a lot of trials I am asking this question because I am learning this as of now. For example, df[[‘A’,’B’]].dropna()-> simple one
[(x,y) for x,y in df[[‘A’,’B’]]].values if pd.notnull(x) and pd.notnull(y)]-> a slightly complicated one. I am listing down these cool comprehension steps to get more familiarized with it

Comment: @jezrael, your code actually creates two separate columns and applies count, instead of generating 1 column, containing the count indexed by region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a `DF` constructed as shown:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(region=np.random.choice(list('ABC'), 10, p='0.3 0.3 0.4'.split()), 
                  location=['loc_'+'{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]))
```

1) An obvious solution would be to `groupby` and aggregate `count`:

```
df.groupby('region')['location'].agg(['count'])
```

2) Leveraging the use of `itertools.groupby` to perform grouping using a dictionary comprehension in vanilla python:

```
from itertools import groupby
L = df[['region', 'location']].values.tolist()
## List-comp : [[k, len(list(g))] for k, g in groupby(sorted(L), key=lambda x: x[0])]
d = dict((k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(sorted(L), key=lambda x: x[0]))
pd.DataFrame(dict(count=list(d.values())), d.keys()).sort_index().rename_axis('region')
```

3) Could also be done using `groupby.apply` function:

```
df.groupby('region')['location'].apply(lambda x: x.count()).to_frame('count')
```

4) Use `np.bincount` after converting the `object` columns to `categorical` type.

```
r = df.region.astype('category')
a = np.bincount(r.cat.codes.values)
pd.DataFrame(dict(count=a), r.cat.categories).rename_axis(r.name)
```

All these approaches produce:

[image]

***Note***: Additionally, a `reset_index` at the end of these syntaxes would get you a flattened `DF` as desired.